Issues with DBT Compilation and Jinja
I'm running into issues with my DBT set up. Aafter setting up some linters and formatting checks, it won't run, and the error is quite vague:

Unable to do partial parsing because of a version mismatch Encountered an error: Compilation Error expected token ‘end of print statement’, got ‘string’ line 15 {{ return “” }}

This seems to be a problem with my Jinja2 installation, but this error is still too unclear for me to figure out what might be happening.
I have the following versions:
dbt-bigquery:   1.7.1
dbt-common:     1.5.0
dbt-core:       1.7.10
sqlfluff:       3.1.0
Jinja2:         3.1.3

I feel a little lost, so any advice would be helpful!

You may want to add brackets to the return:
so instead of
{{ return "" }}

it should look like
{{ return("") }}

